# Export Video With Watermark using GPUImage iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, gpuimage, avassetwriter

I has tried the most of the question related to GPUImage (GPUImageMovieWriter) to export the video.I write this code to create and export the video.This gives the black screen and does not export the video.

In the **ViewController.h** file..

```
  {
    GPUImageMovie *movieFile;
    GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter;
    GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
    GPUImageUIElement *uiElementInput;
  }
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *vwVideo;
```

In the **ViewController.m** file

```
- (void) editVideo { 
    NSURL *sampleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"sophie" withExtension:@"mov"];

    GPUImagePicture *overlay = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-icon-180.png"] smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
    [overlay processImage];

   movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
   movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
   movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;

   filter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
   [(GPUImageBrightnessFilter*)filter setBrightness:0.0];

 GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
 blendFilter.mix = 1.0;

 UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-20)];
 contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

 UIImageView *ivTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 147, 59)];
ivTemp.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-icon-180.png"];
[contentView addSubview:ivTemp];

UILabel *lblDemo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 30)];
lblDemo.text = @"Did";
lblDemo.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
lblDemo.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
lblDemo.tag = 1;
lblDemo.hidden = YES;
lblDemo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[contentView addSubview:lblDemo];

uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:contentView];
[filter addTarget:blendFilter];
[uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];


// Only rotate the video for display, leave orientation the same for recording
GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)vwVideo;
[filter addTarget:filterView];
[movieFile addTarget:filter];
[blendFilter addTarget:filterView];    
[filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
    if (frameTime.value/frameTime.timescale == 2) {
        [contentView viewWithTag:1].hidden = NO;
    }
    [uiElementInput update];
}];

// In addition to displaying to the screen, write out a processed version of the movie to disk
NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.mov"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
NSLog(@"%@",pathToMovie);
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie] size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)];
[filter addTarget:movieWriter];

movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Saved");
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, nil, nil, nil);
}];}
```

This code does not export the video to document directory or does not save.Please help me.How to add watermark on the video.
**Note** : I also tried the AvassetWriter and AVMutableComposition to create the video,but that does not work in iOS 8 ,but work in ios 7 .

Answer (score 0):

i tried your code, and i found that you use wrong target. i have modified it, you can try it again.

NSURL *sampleURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];

```
movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithURL:sampleURL];
movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = NO;

filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
blendFilter.mix = 1.0;

UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                               0,
                                                               [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,
                                                               [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-20)];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImageView *ivTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 147, 59)];
ivTemp.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"db"];
[contentView addSubview:ivTemp];

UILabel *lblDemo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 30)];
lblDemo.text = @"Did---啊啊啊";
lblDemo.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:30];
lblDemo.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
lblDemo.tag = 1;
lblDemo.hidden = YES;
lblDemo.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[contentView addSubview:lblDemo];

uiElementInput = [[GPUImageUIElement alloc] initWithView:contentView];
[filter addTarget:blendFilter];
[uiElementInput addTarget:blendFilter];


// Only rotate the video for display, leave orientation the same for recording
GPUImageView *filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[filterView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[movieFile addTarget:filter];
[blendFilter addTarget:filterView];
[self.view addSubview:filterView];

__unsafe_unretained GPUImageUIElement *weakUIElementInput = uiElementInput;
[filter setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock:^(GPUImageOutput * filter, CMTime frameTime){
    if (frameTime.value/frameTime.timescale == 2) {
        [contentView viewWithTag:1].hidden = NO;
    }
    [weakUIElementInput update];
}];

// In addition to displaying to the screen, write out a processed version of the movie to disk
NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.mov"];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
NSLog(@"%@",pathToMovie);
movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie] size:CGSizeMake(640.0, 480.0)];
[blendFilter addTarget:movieWriter];

movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
movieFile.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
[movieFile enableSynchronizedEncodingUsingMovieWriter:movieWriter];

[movieWriter startRecording];
[movieFile startProcessing];

[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Saved");
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(pathToMovie, nil, nil, nil);
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me reply ..I try your code ...thanks